# Validation accuracy is much less than Training accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am using **MOSI** dataset for the multimodal sentiment analysis, where for now I am training the model for text dataset only. For text, I am using glove embeddings of **300** dimensions for processing text. My total vocab size is 2173 and my padded sequence length is 30. My target array is  `[0,0,0,0,0,0,1]` where left most is highly -ve and right most highly +ve.

I am splitting the dataset like this

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(WDatasetX, y7, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)`

My tokenization process is

```
MAX_NB_WORDS = 3000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS,oov_token = "OOV")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(Text_X_Train)
tokenized_X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(Text_X_Train)
tokenized_X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(Text_X_Test)
```

My embedding matrix:

```
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1
emb_mean=0
def embedding_matrix_filteration():
    all_embs = np.stack(list(embeddings_index.values()))
    print(all_embs.shape)
    emb_mean, emb_std = np.mean(all_embs), np.std(all_embs)
    print(emb_mean)
    embedding_matrix = np.random.normal(emb_mean, emb_std, (vocab_size, embed_dim)) gives the matrix of specified
                                                                    size filled with values from gauss distribution
    print(embedding_matrix.shape)
     print("length of word2id:",len(word2id))
    embeddedCount = 0
    not_found = []
    for word, idx in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word.lower())
        if word == ' ':
            embedding_vector = np.zeros_like(emb_mean)
        if embedding_vector is not None: 
            embedding_matrix[idx] = embedding_vector
            embeddedCount += 1
        else:
            print(word)
            print("$$$")
    print('total embedded:',embeddedCount,'common words')# words common between glove vector and wordset
    print("length of word2id:",len(word2id))
    print(len(embedding_matrix))
    return embedding_matrix

emb = embedding_matrix_filteration()
```

### Model Architecture:

Embedding Layer:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(
    vocab_size,
    300,
    weights=[emb],
    trainable=False,
    input_length=sequence_length
)
```

My model:

```
from keras import regularizers,layers

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(512,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(512,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256)))#kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

For some reason when my training accuracy reached 80%, val. accuracy still remains very low. I have tried different regularization techniques, optimizers, loss functions, but the result is the same. I don't know why.

[image]

Please Help!!

Edit: The total no. of tokens are 2719 and the total no. of sentences (including test and train dataset ) are 2183.

```
Compiler: model.compile(optimizer='adam',         
loss='mean-squred-error',
metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

### UPDATED STATS:

I have decreased the label size from 7 to 3 i.e. [0,1,0] -> +ve, neutral ,-ve.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(16,activation='relu'))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Compiled:

```
model.compile( 
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00005),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Graphs:
[image]

Training:
[image]

But loss is still high and Also, I have stratified the dataset.

Comment: share your `model.compile`.

Comment: What does this mean: `My target array is  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`? Does that represent 7 training instances with 0/1 binary labels, or does that represent one training instance with 7 outputs? If the latter, what is the possible range of each value? Binary 0/1 or a floating point number?

Comment: I have hot encoded the output, like it is sentiment analysis, [1,0,0,0,0,0,0] represent highly -ve, [0,0,0,1,0,0,0] represents neutral and [0,0,0,0,1,0,0] represents slightly +ve. I have changed my whole dataset label to this form i.e. in a vector of size (1,7).   "My target array is  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]" I was using this line to tell about my label structure. Therefore, My label/output is in the form of a vector  of size(1,7).

Comment: Have you tried using the basic DNN instead of RNN?

Comment: No, I think RNN's are better at NLP's task than DNN. Especially Bi-directionals are more better. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of recommendations:

1. Use `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `mean_squared_error`, it can help you a lot when doing classification (although the latter could also work, the former also does it better).
2. Are all your labels mutually exclusive? If then, use `softmax` + `categorical_crossentropy`, otherwise (e.g. label appears like `[1,0,0,0,0,0,1]` use `sigmoid` + `binary_crossentropy`.
3. Decrease the size of the model initially, and only if the overfitting problem persists use `Dropout()`. Use only one layer of LSTM.
4. Reduce the number of units (even if you have one single LSTM cell (`64`/`128` would probably suffice).
5. You can use bidirectional LSTM (I would even opt for bidirectional GRUs since they are simpler, to see how the performance behaves).
6. Ensure that you do a `stratified split` (in this way, certain examples definitely appear both in the training set and in the validation set, also keeping a good proportion.
7. Start with a small(er) learning rate (`0.0001`/`0.00005`).
8. Establish an objective/correct baseline. If your data is very little, particularly when working on a multi-modal dataset(you fetch only the "text"), you work only on text, with 7 different classes, then it is probable you will not reach a very high accuracy.

Bear in mind that, in order to have a reasonable final result in your case, you need to employ a data-centric approach, rather than a model-centric one. Regardless of the possible improvements, if the data is scarce + not comprehensive, you will not be able to achieve great results.

Comment: yeah! I applied every point of you. And it worked . But I reached upto validation accuracy of 0.64 but the loss is 0.91 and it does not decrease after it. So, is it limit of this model? If not what does this 0.91 or 91% valid. loss signify and what should I do. I have updated the stats in Edit section od this question.

Comment: I also updated and added another suggestion. I really am happy to see the performance of your model increased.

Comment: At the same time, I think it now depends on the exact validation split how much accuracy you will obtain, and also some hyperparameter tuning.

Answer (score 3):

A large difference between Train and Validation stats typically indicates overfitting of models to the Train data.

To minimize this I do a few things

1. reduce the size of the model.
2. Add a few dropout or similar layers in the model. I have had good success with using these layers: `layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.8),`

See guidance here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#strategies_to_prevent_overfitting

Comment: I have tried all overfitting prevention techniques and I've tried 2 Bidirectional and one dense layer too with optimizers and regularizers but the result is same.

Comment: How much data is in your dataset? Could there be insufficient data to grasp the complexity of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: there are 2179 unique words in tokenizers. And each sequence is padded with length 30

Comment: what is your `model.compile`? Add it in the question.

Comment: optimizer is adam and loss is mean-squared-error . I have also tried Binarycrossentropy

Answer (score 2):

How long is your dataset (how many sentences), 2179 tokens does not seems like much, it seems to me like your model is way too big for the task. I wouldn't add 4 layers of LSTM, I would go with 1 or 2.

```py
from keras import regularizers,layers

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

As for the training, 200 epoch seems long, if your model desn't seem to converge after 20 I would reset and try with a simpler architecture.

Comment: Val. accuracy revolves around 30% after 6 epoch and does not increase with training accuracy which reached 50% in 9 th epoch

Comment: I also tried removing the second last dense layer and LSTM neurons to 16 too but the result is the same.

Comment: How many sentences are present in your dataset ?

Comment: I am sorry about the wrong info, the total no. of tokens are 2719 and the total no. of sentences (including test and train dataset ) are 2183.

Comment: This is way too little to train a recurrent neural network. I would use simpler approach like tfidf-svc or maybe fine-tuning a deep learning model already trained for that task on a bigger corpus.

Comment: But I have seen various research papers using same dataset and glove embeddings , and achieving good results

Comment: @GautamGoyal Can you send me those papers ? I'll take a look

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Multimodal-Sentiment-Analysis-with-Fusion-Network-Li-Chen/2bebbc1f4f0718ad10649ea4a84b69430ec36122 and https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Proposed-multi-level-context-extraction-and-attention-based-contextual-inter-modal-fusion_fig2_337939180 this one is pretty similar, ... https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9131698 , etc.

Comment: @GautamGoyal I could have a quick look at the papers, and I notices several things: 1. You focus on the text which is only part on the info where the multimodal models have both text, video and audio, is that correct ? 2. The performance in CMU-MOSI is lower when using only the text data (~67%). 3. Because the CMU-MOSI corpus is smaller, some of the paper seem to use these algorithms for binary classification instead of the 7 classes which is easier. 4. Decrease your learning rate.

Comment: 1. That can be a issue. I should fuse the modalities first. 2. But my valid. accuracy still remains under 35%. 3. & 4. I will try it